# 2 Jquery functions inside 1 click event

Tags: jquery, function

Actually I can say I'm new to heavy use of Jquery and JS. 
I was pure PHP dev so I come up to here and hope you guys can help me.

What I want to do is popup a form with 2 buttons edit(`#editar`) and delete(`#eliminar`)

(`#editar`) will change the `.val()` of an input and (`#eliminar`) will remove the clicked object from DOM.

But with the code I have when I change for the first time no problem at all, then when I try for a second time it triggers the function twice, 3 times, 4 times and so on...

Is the way I'm coding the correct to achieve this? I mean those 2 functions inside the click event.

I will really aprecciate your words and any help provided.

```
$("#pedido").on("click", "a.editprod", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this).attr('apeid');
    var c = parseInt($("li[lid="+t+"]").attr("cantp"));
    alert(t);
    var htmleditor = '<p>Editar Cantidad:</p><table><tr><th><a class="menos" href="#" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">-</a></th><th><input id="" class="cantprod" type="number" value="'+c+'"></th><th><a href="#" class="mas" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">+</a></th></tr></table><button id="editar" data-theme="b" >Cambiar Cantidad</button><button id="eliminar" data-theme="a">Eliminar Producto</button>';
    $("#datoseditor").html(htmleditor);
    $("#editor").trigger("create");
    $("#editor").popup("open");
        $("#datoseditor").on("click", "#editar", function(e){
            var ce = $("#datoseditor").find('input').val();
            alert(ce);
            $("li[lid="+t+"]").attr("cantp",ce);
            $('span[id="bcantp'+t+'"]').html(ce);
            $('input[data-id="'+t+'"]').val(ce);
            alert(t);
            $("#editor").popup("close");
            });
       $("#datoseditor").on("click", "#eliminar", function(e){
        $("li[lid="+t+"]").remove();
        $("#ppedidos").listview('refresh');
        $('input[data-id="'+t+'"]').remove();
           alert('Producto Eliminado!');
        $("#editor").popup("close");
    });

    });
```

UPDATE:

WORKING CODE

```
function ventanaEditar(){
        window.prodpedidoId=$(this).attr("apeid");
        var c=parseInt($("li[lid="+window.prodpedidoId+"]").attr("cantp"));
        var htmleditor='<p>Editar Cantidad:</p><table><tr><th><a class="menos" href="#" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">-</a></th><th><input id="" class="cantprod" type="number" value="'+c+'"></th><th><a href="#" class="mas" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">+</a></th></tr></table><button id="editar" data-theme="b" >Cambiar Cantidad</button><button id="eliminar" data-theme="a">Eliminar Producto</button>';
        $("#datoseditor").html(htmleditor);
        $("#editor").trigger("create");
        $("#editor").popup("open")}

    function editarProducto(){
        var ce=$("#datoseditor").find("input").val();
        $("li[lid="+window.prodpedidoId+"]").attr("cantp",ce);
        $('span[id="bcantp'+window.prodpedidoId+'"]').html(ce);
        $('input[data-id="'+window.prodpedidoId+'"]').val(ce);
        $("#editor").popup("close")}

    function elimProducto(){
        $("li[lid="+window.prodpedidoId+"]").remove();
        $('input[data-id="'+window.prodpedidoId+'"]').remove();
        alert("Producto Eliminado!");
        $("#ppedidos").listview("refresh");
        $("#editor").popup("close")};

    $("#pedido").on("click", "a.editprod", (ventanaEditar));
    $("#datoseditor").on("click", "#editar", (editarProducto));
    $("#datoseditor").on("click", "#eliminar", (elimProducto));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "on" with a selector, each time you open a new popup. i.e.

```
$("#datoseditor").on("click", "#editar",
$("#datoseditor").on("click", "#eliminar"
```

This version of `on` actually hangs around long after the elements have gone, so you can connect them outside your popup code (registered once only). e.g.

```
$("#datoseditor").on("click", "#editar", function(e){
    var ce = $("#datoseditor").find('input').val();
    alert(ce);
    $("li[lid="+t+"]").attr("cantp",ce);
    $('span[id="bcantp'+t+'"]').html(ce);
    $('input[data-id="'+t+'"]').val(ce);
    alert(t);
    $("#editor").popup("close");
    });
$("#datoseditor").on("click", "#eliminar", function(e){
    $("li[lid="+t+"]").remove();
    $("#ppedidos").listview('refresh');
    $('input[data-id="'+t+'"]').remove();
       alert('Producto Eliminado!');
    $("#editor").popup("close");
});

$("#pedido").on("click", "a.editprod", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this).attr('apeid');
    var c = parseInt($("li[lid="+t+"]").attr("cantp"));
    alert(t);
    var htmleditor = '<p>Editar Cantidad:</p><table><tr><th><a class="menos" href="#" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">-</a></th><th><input id="" class="cantprod" type="number" value="'+c+'"></th><th><a href="#" class="mas" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true">+</a></th></tr></table><button id="editar" data-theme="b" >Cambiar Cantidad</button><button id="eliminar" data-theme="a">Eliminar Producto</button>';
    $("#datoseditor").html(htmleditor);
    $("#editor").trigger("create");
    $("#editor").popup("open");
});
```

Comment: how can i pass var's to #editar / #eliminar functions if they are now outside the main function?

Comment: @CCortina you don't *need* to pass those vars, use `this` to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: You need to declare them globally, or change the way you pass information to them. Alternatively keep your existing code layout, but disconnect the `on`'s with matching `off`s when you close it